# SSLProxyMachineCertificatePath certificate selection

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4, mod-ssl, proxypass

How does [SSLProxyMachineCertificatePath](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxymachinecertificatepath) cert selection works? Or does it sends all of them in the request ?